# QGIS KML layer won't show up in Google Maps API

Tags: qgis, kml, layers, google-maps-api

I've trimmed US Census shapefile data to show census blocks in just three states, by editing the attribute table.

I then color coded the states based on values in the table by changing the style in qgis.

Now I want to export the new map as a KML or GeoJson layer. However each time I've tried, the layer will not show up on the Google Maps API basemap.

I believe the API code is correct, because when I use a test kml file from online, it shows.

I've tried exporting using various attributes (no symbology, feature symbology, symbol layer symbology, wsg 84,etc). I've tried hosting the file on dropbox, and my server for my website. I've tried geojson and kml and the layer simply won't show.

The file is 300+ MB. And Inspect Element shows no console errors

When I open the file in a text editor, things seem fine. The tags look closed.

I'm not sure what exactly is causing this problem. Is there an alternative to using QGIS? How can I get the Census data as a layer on my Google API project?